# onAuthStateChanged doesn't seem to work with React context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently following the book "The road to React with Firebase" by Robin Wieruch. The problem I have is that my authUser from Firebase becomes null when I make a refresh of a page that consumes from the Context API.

Here is my app.js

```
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import LandingPage from './Landing';
import AccountPage from './Account';
import withAuthentication from './withAuthentication';

import * as routes from '../constants/routes';

const App = () =>
        <Router>
        <div>
        <h3 className="alt-h3" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>Soundyladder</h3>

          <Navigation />
          <hr/>

          <Route
            exact path={routes.LANDING}
            component={LandingPage}
          />


              <Route
            exact path={routes.ACCOUNT}
            component={AccountPage}
          />
        </div>
      </Router>

export default withAuthentication(App);
```

As you can see, the app.js is using a high order component.

withAuthentication.js:

```
import AuthUserContext from './AuthUserContext';

const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
    class withAutnetication extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                authUser: null
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {

            firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
                authUser != null ? this.setState({ authUser }) : this.setState({ authUser: null });

            });

        }

        render() {
            const { authUser } = this.state;
            console.log(this.state);
            return (

                <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
                    <Component { ...this.props } />
                </AuthUserContext.Provider>
            )
        }
    }

    return withAutnetication;
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

And as you can see here, I provide the Context API so that every component below App.js can consume from It.

Here is AuthUserContext:

```
import React from 'react';

const AuthUserContext = React.createContext(null);

export default AuthUserContext;
```

The problem is that when I visit the account page, and then refresh the page, the authUser becomes null.

Account.js:

```
const AccountPage = () =>
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        {authUser =>

            <div>
                <h1>Account: {authUser.email}</h1>
                <PasswordForgetForm />
                <PasswordChangeForm />
            </div>
        }
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>

    export default AccountPage;
```

However, when I'm at the LandingPage and refresh the page, the authUser don't become null.

Here is my landingpage:

```
const LandingPage = () =>
    <div>
        <h1>Landing Page</h1>
    </div>

export default LandingPage;
```

But If I try to consume authUser from the Context API in the landing page, like I do in the account page, I get the same error: the authUser becomes null.

It seems to be something wrong with the Context API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the auth strategy is in the "The road to react with Firebase" book, but the problem you are experiencing can be explained simply like this.

### Account page reload

At the time of the first render (right after you have refreshed the page), React first mounts all the available content. Then it fires the `componentDidMount` method in your `withAuthentication` HOC.

This means, at the time of the first render (right after you have refreshed the page) the context value `authUser` is `null`.

React throws an error (this is what is happening right?) and then stops the execution. Thus never reaching your `componentDidMount` in the HOC.

```
Cannot read property 'email' of null
```

### Landing page reload

Here, React doesn't stop execution because it can render everything. Then fires the `componentDidMount` in the HOC and firebase gets the user (async). By the time you navigate to the "account page" the user has been loaded and thus you `authUser` is no longer `null`.

### Potentail simple fix

Again, not sure what kind of Auth strategy the book provides, but to go around this, you can simply do something along these lines in your HOC

```
render() {
  const { authUser } = this.state;

  if (!authUser) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
      <Component { ...this.props } />
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Or you can add a check in your "Account page" likes this

```
<h1>Account: {authUser ? authUser.email : null}</h1>
```

A very rough example can be found [in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pwz3onwrj). I used `setInterval` instead of the firebase auth method. Let me know it it helps and clears things out.